# Firebase database error...unable to load data to my custom adapter

Tags: android-studio

[Exception Error during Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovMs4.png)

[Code where error occors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgi4P.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do not post code as screenshots. Please [edit] the question and post code as [mcve] (in text format)

Comment: As you replace the images with their text, please also add the JSON at `DayCares` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your database you store `longitude` and `latitude` as numbers, while in your `ListDocModel` class you have them as string fields/properties.

The solution is to make `longitude` and `latitude` of type `Long` in your `ListDocModel` class too.